# Ordered parallel execution

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I have an ordered list like `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`. I am passing it to a `Parallel.ForEach` statement. Can I somehow achieve the following ordering of execution of buckets like: process first 3 items `[1, 2, 3]` where ordering in bucket itself is not mandatory and can be `[2, 1, 3]` for instance. Then process next 3 items `[4, 5, 6]`, etc?

Comment: Are you saying you want to shuffle each batch of 3 elements?

Comment: No, I am saying that batches are ordered: first 3, then next 3, but inside bucket ordering may be random - not mandatory to order inside the bucket

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure that you can do this directly. but I would suggest you to divide the input list in to smaller lists and then you can process each sublist with `Parallel.Foreach`.

```
List<int> fruits = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
List<List<int>> ls = new List<List<int>>();
for (int i = 0; i < fruits.Count; i += 3)
{
    ls.Add(fruits.GetRange(i, Math.Min(3, fruits.Count - i)));
}
foreach (List<int> group in ls)
{
    Parallel.ForEach(group, fruit =>
    {
    });
}
```

3 is the length of small list.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeurl I was going to suggest something similar actually - keep in mind that the Microsoft documentation for Parallel.ForEach does explicitly state that they don't guarantee a particular order of execution, so you almost have to do something like this.

Comment: Hmm, this works. I was thinking to try this but I didn't believe it will work :)

Comment: This seems to work perfectly with my requirements. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

Even if the accepted answer fulfills requirements perfectly, there is some overhead in it. First of all, as we are talking about the TPL, the volume of data arrays is probably big, so simply creating that much arrays is very memory consuming.
Also, solution suggested by @viveknuna does not guarantee the order for the chunks. If it is ok, you probably should use the answer from @DmitryBychenko with a small update:

```
const int chunkSize = 3;
var array = Enumerable.Range(1, 9).ToArray();
// get the chunks for indexes for array sized in group of 3
var partitioner = Partitioner.Create(0, array.Length, chunkSize);

// use all the system resources
var parallelOptions = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount };

// use the partitioner for a chunks, so outer parallel foreach
// will start a task for all the chunks, [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]
Parallel.ForEach(partitioner, parallelOptions, part =>
    {
        // inner foreach will handle part of the chunk in parallel
        Parallel.ForEach(array.Skip(part.Item1).Take(chunkSize), parallelOptions, value =>
            {
                // handle the array value in parallel
            });
    });
```

In the given code, if you set the for the `ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism` to the `1`, you'll get the desired ordered parallel execution, chunk by chunk.

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try tomorrow.